# CakePHP Find Conditions Optional Parameters

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to fetch rows following filters passed by POST to my Controller, but the parameters are optional and sometimes they could be empty, and the rule is: whenever a field is passed empty, fetch all rows ( dont filter ).

I can do this in raw sql:

```
SELECT * from users where id = $param OR $param IS NULL
```

But I dont know how to do this CakePHP way. Tried a lot of combinations. My present stage is some like:

[...]

```
'conditions' => array(
                        array(
                            'OR' => array(
                                'Request.id' => $this->request->data['Search']['id'],
                            ),
```

Basically, I dont know how to do the 'OR $param IS NULL' part of the query.
In the present conditions, I can sucefully fetch rows when I pass a 'id' param from the view, but if I dont pass anything ( null ID ), the result is 0 rows, and should be all rows.

I'm using Postgres as SGBD.

Thanks

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION**

Following the idea of @Vin000, I can do:

```
$conditions = array();

        if(isset($this->request->data['Search']['id'] ) and $this->request->data['Search']['id'] != null ) 
        { 
            $conditions['Request.id'] = $this->request->data['Search']['id']; 
        }
```

which solves my problem.

Comment: Together the two clauses seem incorrect. `id = $param` implies $param is an integer  or UUID since it is the value of the ID column. `$param is NULL` implies $param is the name of a column within your users table. I think you want to program in php - if $param has a value use the conditions clause. If the $param is not used, do not use the conditions clause

Answer (score -1):

You should use $this->request->params or $this->params->query if you're passing your data from the URL. You can't access data in $this->request->post if you're sending it from URL. Please add few conditions like as below.

```
    $conditions = array();

            if (!empty($this->params->query['keywords']))
                $conditions[] = array($this->params->query['search_by'] . ' like' => "%" . $this->params->query['keywords'] . "%");

            if (!empty($this->request->params['pass']))
                $conditions[] = //Your conditions
```

I personally suggest you to pass query parameters from URL so you can know that what the values are and for which parameter.

Comment: I misspelled it, I'm passing from POST and not from URL...I'll edit my question.